# React beautiful DND - "Unable to find draggable with id: X"

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to use react-beautiful-dnd for drag n drop sorting of a list but my elements are not draggable and I get `Unable to find draggable with id: X`. I have cross-check my code with examples in docs but unable to find what I need to fix. I am using constant `id` for `key` and `draggableId` prop.

Code:[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rbd-cant-drag-1-bii0hp)

Edit 1: I expected the code to be able to drag and rearrange items but will return to their initial position as state update is not implemented

Comment: same thing here ? https://codesandbox.io/s/k260nyxq9v

Comment: Yup , actually just converted it to functional component and removed onDraghandler with styles, none of which should affect the drag functionality I assume

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem. Try disabling React's Strict Mode. That fixed it for me. https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

There's an open issue for this with react-beautiful-dnd here https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2350. Hopefully compatibility with strict mode will be fixed soon. Until then removing strict mode works around the issue.

Comment: Thank you , I switched to [dnd-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dnd-kit/core) but hope this answer helps someone

Comment: Having to disable strict mode is bad practise. There is a workaround but Atlassian's claim to update the module with critical fixes does not ring true in my ears. Strict mode seems pretty critical to me. That is why I would opt for the fork that does get updated like @dybzon mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 15):

Late to the party here, but I was facing the same issue. It turns out that there's a fork of `react-beautiful-dnd` called `@hello-pangea/dnd`. You can [find it here](https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd).

This fork has the same API, but unlike `react-beautiful-dnd` it works in strict mode **and** seems to be actively maintained.

It's easy to switch over because they use the same API. Simply add the package

`npm i @hello-pangea/dnd` or `yarn add @hello-pangea/dnd`

and then change your imports from

```
import {
  Droppable,
  Draggable
} from "react-beautiful-dnd";
```

to

```
import {
  Droppable,
  Draggable
} from "@hello-pangea/dnd";
```

Note that `@hello-pangea/dnd` is typescript based, which means the types are included directly in this package too.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem with **nextjs**

I went into `next.config.js` file and just set `reactStrictMode to false`